# Android: System.currentTImeMillis and DateTime.Now

Tags: android, datetime, time, system

I am making a logging system which logged the data at certain day say on each 7th day. What is the different between using System.currentTimeMillis and DateTime.Now. I know DateTime.Now will change if the user change the date under the setting of the phone.

If System.currentTimeMillis is the way to go for, can I still able to use this line of code to get the week of the year

```
var dateTimeCurrentInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        var calendar = dateTimeCurrentInfo.Calendar;
        var week = calendar.GetWeekOfYear (dateNow, dateTimeCurrentInfo.CalendarWeekRule, dateTimeCurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

At the moment, I used DateTime.Now to get the week.

Comment: Did you forget the xamarin tag? there is no `DateTime.Now` in plain android. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the phone time. Anything else just wraps it in some way

Comment: Sorry I am very new to xamarin.. U mean DateTime.Now is using System.currentTimeMillis indirectly???